# Using addFirst and addLast methods with StringBuilder in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

I would like to use  (For a string array)

```
 public void addFirst(String Element)
 {

 }
```

and

```
public void addLast(String Element){
 }
```

I know the add I would use

```
 public void add(int index, String element) {
int len = names.length;
if (index < len)
  names[index] = element;
else {
  names = Arrays.copyOf(names, len + (index - len + 1));
  names[index] = element;
}
```

}

would I just change index to 0 to element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*addFirst:*

```
  public void addFirst(String Element) {
    add(0, Element);

  }
```

*addLast:*

```
  public void addLast(String Element) {
    add(names.length - 1, Element);
  }
```